# Done everything to forward ports, still closed

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I'm on Linux Mint 18.3 with a wireless router given by my ISP provider and I've been trying port forwarding to no avail. This is a problem that I've had for a long time.

Among other things, `netstat -rn` displays:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp3s0
```

Among other things, `ifconfig` displays (I'm connected through Ethernet to the wireless router):

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:f5:aa:f1:4e:bb  
          inet addr:192.168.0.200  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2804:14d:148e:9225:1c98:5f89:7b9:e731/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2804:14d:148e:9225:9cc1:4756:f00:c752/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::79ea:4ce1:8bb9:56b6/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd9d:5943:d5d1::1d3/128 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21605 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29222 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
```

With this data in hand, I've already set up my static IP to use `192.168.0.200`, `255.255.255.0` as my Netmask, and `192.168.0.1` as my Gateway. Below is a screenshot of my configuration for the Ethernet network. DNS also is static.

[image]

I've already added the following port forwardings:

[image]

DMZ Host is disabled in the router. Firewalls are disabled in the router and on PC. The application that requires these ports is open when I'm checking the ports, and it can't connect nevertheless.

Weirdly enough, all port checkers that I've already tried also say that port *80* is closed - is that normal?

Am I doing something wrong? Did I leave something out? I've already scoured the internet without success, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If I'm reading your port forwarding rules correctly.. you only port forward 40102, 40103, and 3282. So 80 IS closed because it is not port-forwarded (and you REALLY don't want your router web management is open to the WAN side). Are you running some sort of service on your machine (192.168.0.200) that accepts connection on port 40102, 40103 and 3282?

Comment: @Darius Yes, I am, and I keep it running while I do my checks.

Comment: And those services are running? Have you tested from a machine within the same LAN to see if that works? If yes, you can try something like www.grc.com and check their Shields Up page and get their website to probe your particular port. Another possibility is that you may be behind a CGNAT or your ISP may blocks most incoming connnection to random ports)

Comment: See [*What is Carrier-Grade NAT?*](https://superuser.com/q/1120843/432690)

Comment: I see you have a global IPv6 address, and based on the port numbers I presume your service is not intended for the general public, so why not try using IPv6 instead of fighting with NAT?

Comment: To explain the "Carrier-Grade" comment: Your ISP very likely doesn't give you a public IPv4 address, but NATs you to whatever address is available. This means you can port forward until you are blue in the face, you'll never be able to reach even your router from the outside (unless the router establishes a connection first). Using IPv6 is the simplest solution to be reachable from the outside, and you don't even need to port forward it, as the local devices will have different IPv6 addresses.